# Call Articles by Category

Tags: django, django-views

I am new at learning Django. I want to build a system that does exactly as seen in the link below. When you hit the page the articles are rendered by latest post. This is easy, but I want to have the categories section that allows the user to select a category and filter the page to display the related articles. You can see the way net-tuts did this with the topics widget in the side-bar.

https://tutsplus.com/courses/

Is there already a built in feature for this? I think my problem is I do not know what keywords to look for. I have tried tags and categories but cannot find what I am looking for. Any help in the right direction would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Django is a framework, not a cms, so how your content is structured and how you present it is up to you. Now having posts by category is a standard feature of blogging apps, and there are quite a few blogging apps for Django, so you could either use an existing one or have a look at the code to see how they solved the problem (which is kind of trivial FWIW).